# how do you use /scoreboard to test for a non specific item

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I just had help with :

```
/scoreboard players set @a[team=Ninja] jump 0 {SelectedItem:{id:minecraft:ender_eye}}
```

But I was wondering if you could have it so it was any item this would be a great help as other wise I would have to use multiple command blocks this wouldn't be a problem if I wasn't doing a one block command.

Comment: Can you be more specific? What are you trying to achieve? Are you saying you want to test for absolutely any item?

Comment: yes  that is exactly what I am trying to do but if I  can list more that one I team that would be ok but any item would be better

Answer (score 1):

You could just test for `SelectedItem:{}`, as the same method can be applied for itemframes. But if it doesn't work then you could test for `Count:0b` and invert the signal.

Comment: Please accept answers that helped you by clicking on the shaded gray tick, that helps other people find the answers they need quicker